# Rxjs: how to get latest emitted value from a observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

As the demo shows, as the title said

```js
const { combineLatest, interval, of } = rxjs;
const { first, last, sample, take, withLatestFrom } = rxjs.operators;

const numbers = interval(1000);

const takeFourNumbers = numbers.pipe(take(4));
takeFourNumbers.subscribe(x => console.log('Next: ', x));
setTimeout(()=>{
 console.log('how can we get the latest value which is 1?');
 takeFourNumbers.pipe(first()).subscribe(v=>console.log(v,'actual get'))
},2500)
// Logs:
// Next: 0
// Next: 1
// how can we get the latest value which is 1?
// Next: 2
// 0 actual get
// Next: 3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rxjs@7.5.5/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

In my case, I just want to get the latest value and do a one-time job. How can I do it?

I am thinking if we have an operator like `takeLatest()` or `latest()`? But I didn't find anyone.

Comment: Well, a subscription should get you the latest emitted value, that's kind of the point of a subscription, isn't it?

Comment: your second subscription is taking place after 2.5 seconds so I think 2 should be considered as latest value

Comment: @Yogi what if 2 will be triggered after a very long time?

Comment: @JeremyThille It will give you all emitted values one by one, not just give you the latest one. And I didn't find operator like `latest()`...

Comment: @xianshenglu updated the code, try it out and see if this is what you want.

Comment: Maybe `lastValueFrom( observable )` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille no, because it only works when observable is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem boils down to sharing provider(data source) or "Hot vs Cold" observables, you want the latest value to be shared across different subscriptions so you basically want a hot observable, Observable returned from interval operator is cold so you need to make it hot and doing so is quite simple:

```
const takeFourNumbers = numbers.pipe(take(4), shareReplay(1));
```

now it doesn't matter how many times you subscribe to it, all subscribers will share the value

edit: my bad, it should be shareReplay so that it gives you last emitted value as soon as you subscribe to it so now you should get 1 from that subscription inside setTimeout

Comment: Sorry, sir. In this case, I got `2` not `1`. Also, in many cases, I can't change the observable. For example, `takeFourNumbers ` was provided by other libs.

Comment: you can pipe it and create a new one with you own modifications, that same thing can be written like:
```
const thirdPartyObs = numbers.pipe(take(4));
const myObs = thirdPartyObs.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

Comment: @xianshenglu here, try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-wave-vfk2ro?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: that's for your answer. However, in this case, it won't work again. See this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ofckds?file=index.ts

Comment: both subscriptions need to subscribe to `takeFourNumbersShareReplay`, if that's not possible to do then sorry bud, there's not much to do.